# how to decode base64 image

Tags: php, base64, file-get-contents

i use file_get_contents facing this issue , how i can make it become image with base64?

[Click Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqxla.png)

if i direct use browser type the url, it will return script like below script:

[Click Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPLxj.png)

Comment: Your "direct url" looks like straight up HTML, is it a 404?

Comment: "Direct url" Return Status Code:200 OK

Response Header : 
content-encoding:gzip
content-language:en-US
content-length:2416
content-type:text/html

Comment: Then it's not an image

Comment: yes, that is a script, the script will make it become base64 image.
This is the Url : 
https://vrl.lta.gov.sg/lta/vrl/action/captchaImg?FUNCTION_ID=F0501015ET

Comment: That page is intentionally being obfuscated, the span ID's are random. And there's javascript that is also random to stitch it all back together.

Comment: yes ,you are right ,the span ID's are random.
but , i don know why i direct url can view the html script? but when i use file_get_content just return obfuscated code?

Comment: I'd say they've got user agent checking. Try using cURL where you can send a different user agent string. The result isn't just base64, it's more like a binary format, possibly even encrypted as well.

Comment: hi scuzzy, any way can make my IMAGE 1 picture  display with js code only?

Comment: I'm not sure sorry, I'm not able to see anything quickly.

Comment: hi Scuzzy , do you have email?may i send the code for you try see?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this html sample

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

add, tested code:

```
<img alt='EI3' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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' />
```

you can access information reference at https://www.base64-image.de/

Comment: Hi there, the file_get_contents response  is not the base64 code, please look my image 1

Comment: <?php
        $im = file_get_contents('filename.gif');
        $imdata = base64_encode($im);      
?>

Comment: <img alt='Embedded Image' src='data:image/png;base64,H4sIAAAAAAAAAG2XW5OquhKA3/evcLOrVmnpEhBRHMc5BQii4hUvg1Pz.........gzyefogPw5e/wLHlK3Djg0AAA==' />

hi i have try your method, the image cannot display out.